# Finding the optimal number of clusters in a graph

Tags: matlab, graph, cluster-analysis

I am using the symmetric nonnegative matrix factorization algorithm (SYMNMF) in matlab for clustering a graph G. The inputs are:

- Adjacency Matrix X
- Desired number of clusters K

I need to define K such as:

- The number of edges running between clusters is as small as possible.

Is there any algorithm I can use to find the optimal number of cluters given the adjacency matrix of the graph?

Comment: I don't think there is an optimal way for clustering specifically for SYNNMF, more importantly, the cluster method is always more dependent on the Data then the feature extraction method. Cluster makes the data more sparse for NMF process, try K-means, it should work fine for edges, alternatively, try edge detection and use something like a Gaussian (or Gaussian mixture if you are advanced) to cluster.

Comment: Can't you run the algorithm for different values of K, and then see which result has the smallest "number of edges running between clusters"?

Comment: A. Donda k=1 has 0, but is uninteresting.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to adapt the **elbow method** that is popular with k-means.

The number of edges across clusters should be increasing with k. At k=1, all edges are within the cluster. ;-)

Try different values of k, and choose the largest k that doesn't cause a strong increase in edges lost.

Comment: Increasing k gradually can be a solution. but it is time consuming.

I will use it anyways since there is no other options.